# I can't run methods on the element in my callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I am temporarily adding a background color before lazyload loads my image, since the img element does not support pseudo classes, i have opted to use a span just before it with the same dimensions and give it a background colour of the most dominent color of the image. I need to be able to hide that span once the image is loaded, but i cannot seem to access other dom elements in the callback. I am using verlok/lazyload

so for callback function(el) i have tried to get the element before like this el.before() but i get an error saying 'before is not a function'

HTML

```
<span class="img_overlay" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#cccccc"></span>

<img class="card-img-top" data-src="URL_TO_IMG">
```

JS

```
   var lazyLoadInstance = new LazyLoad({
    elements_selector: "[data-src], [data-bg]",
    load_delay: 1000,
    callback_loaded: function(el) {
        if(el.before().hasClass('img_overlay')) {
                        el.closest('.img_overlay').addClass('class_name');
        }
    },
});
```

if i log the 'el' i get the img element as a string, i expected it to be a dom element. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Given that verlok/lazyload isn't a jquery plugin, I would not expect `el` to be a jquery object (even jquery passes DOM nodes, not jquery objects on its callbacks).  Try `$(el).before()...`

Comment: Also, what are you expecting `.before()` to do?  It inserts content, but you're not passing content.  Did you mean `$(el).parent()` ?

Comment: Why not just load the image as a background image to a `div` and give the div a background color? Problem solved.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i actually do have that solution for places i want to use bg images, but i want to use img's here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `el` is a dom element you need to turn it into a jQuery object in order to use jQuery methods

Also , the proper method for targeting the previous sibling is [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) since `before()` is an insertion method

Try something like:

```
callback_loaded: function(el) {
  var $prev = $(el).prev();
  if ($prev.hasClass('img_overlay')) {
    $prev.addClass('class_name');
  }
},
```

Comment: Thank you, i've learned something today, probably already should've known that :)